# como alinhar verticalmente um button .btn(bootstrap) dentro de uma nav menu fixed top?

Tags: css, bootstrap

[image: <code>inserir a descrição da imagem aqui</code>]

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #888888;
}
#nav h3 {
  margin-left: 3em;
}
#nav-right {
 display: table-cell;
}
.btn {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-container">
<div class="row navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="nav-left">
    <h3>Tiago Fuelber's Portfolio</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3  col-lg-offset-2" id="nav-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">ABOUT</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">PORTFOLIO</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">CONTACT</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O `nav-left` também deve ter `table-cell`

Comment: Eu respondi esses tempos atrás esta mesma pergunta, segue o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153263/alinhando-bot%C3%B5es-no-navbar/153306#153306. espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo usar o atributo `line-height`, para tal defina um `height`para a `nav`.

Assim :

```css
#nav{
  height:60px;
  background-color: #888888;}
#nav h3{
  float:left;
  margin-left: 3em;}
#nav-right{
  float:right;
  margin-right: 7px;
  line-height:60px;
  display: table-cell;}
.btn{
  height: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-container">
<div class="row navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="nav-left">
    <h3>Tiago Fuelber's Portfolio</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3  col-lg-offset-2" id="nav-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">ABOUT</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">PORTFOLIO</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">CONTACT</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oxi...-1, onde meu exemplo testável e verificável pode estar errado ?

Comment: votei +1 pois considero sua solução como ao menos uma boa resposta, não entendi o motivo de alguém dar um voto negativo.

Comment: Sei lá, estamos todos a  aprender, não ligo de receber negativo, desde de que seja instrutivo...